# quick pandas groupby calculations with cumprod

Tags: pandas

This question is linked to [Speedup of pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32129907/speedup-of-pandas-groupby). It is about speeding up a groubby cumproduct calculation. The DataFrame is 2D and has a multi index consisting of 3 integers.

The HDF5 file for the dataframe can be found here: http://filebin.ca/2Csy0E2QuF2w/phi.h5

The actual calculation that I'm performing is similar to this:

```
   >>> phi = pd.read_hdf('phi.h5', 'phi')
   >>> %timeit phi.groupby(level='atomic_number').cumprod()
   100 loops, best of 3: 5.45 ms per loop
```

The other speedup that might be possible is that I do this calculation about 100 times using the same index structure but with different numbers. I wonder if it can somehow cache the index.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I believe `cumprod` doesn't have an Cython groupby implementation.  See related issue here https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4095.  I'm sure a PR would be welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numba appears to work pretty well here.  In fact, these results seem almost too good to be true with the numba function below being about 4,000x faster than the original method and **5x faster than plain `cumprod` without a `groupby`**.  Hopefully these are correct, let me know if there is an error.

```
np.random.seed(1234)
df=pd.DataFrame({ 'x':np.repeat(range(200),4), 'y':np.random.randn(800) })
df = df.sort('x')
df['cp_groupby'] = df.groupby('x').cumprod()

from numba import jit

@jit
def group_cumprod(x,y):
    z = np.ones(len(x))
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i] == x[i-1]:
            z[i] = y[i] * z[i-1]
        else:
            z[i] = y[i]
    return z

df['cp_numba'] = group_cumprod(df.x.values,df.y.values)

df['dif'] = df.cp_groupby - df.cp_numba
```

Test that both ways give the same answer:

```
all(df.cp_groupby==df.cp_numba)
Out[1447]: True
```

Timings:

```
%timeit df.groupby('x').cumprod()
10 loops, best of 3: 102 ms per loop

%timeit df['y'].cumprod()
10000 loops, best of 3: 133 µs per loop

%timeit group_cumprod(df.x.values,df.y.values)
10000 loops, best of 3: 24.4 µs per loop
```

Comment: no this is a nice use of numba. when you have calculations that cannot be easily vectorized (though you did a nice job of that in the other answer), this is often an easy soln. In fact it can usually beat numpy because it does loop lifiting (e.g. doesn't allocate nearly as much memory).

Comment: @Jeff  OK, thanks for confirming.  I guess I'll leave the other answer up too as a comparison.  Btw, I timed in numba without the groupby aspect and that is about 15x faster than regular cumprod.

Comment: your example is not completely comparable though. you don't do nan checking (but not a huge deal, just add a ``if x[i] != x[i]: continue``

Comment: Right, so I should clarify that the above numba function is not as general as the `groupby/cumprod` approach.  In particular, it is assuming that the data has already been sorted by the groupby variable and that there are no missing values.

Comment: if you put in those assumptions you might as well just use pure numpy and get the same performance

Comment: @jtaylor Same performance as which answer? This one (numba) or the other one (pure pandas)?

Answer (score 1):

pure numpy solution, assuming the data is sorted by the index, though no handling of NaN:

```
res = np.empty_like(phi.values)
l = 0
r = phi.index.levels[0]
for i in r:
    phi.values[l:l+i,:].cumprod(axis=0, out=res[l:l+i])
    l += i
```

about 40 times faster on the multiindex data from the question.
Though a problem is that this does rely on how pandas stores the data in its backend array. So it may stop working when pandas changes.

```
>>> phi = pd.read_hdf('phi.h5', 'phi')
>>> %timeit phi.groupby(level='atomic_number').cumprod()
100 loops, best of 3: 4.33 ms per loop
>>> %timeit np_cumprod(phi)
10000 loops, best of 3: 111 µs per loop
```

Comment: It would good to have a pure numpy solution as an option here also, but I'm a little unclear on what exactly you are comparing this 40x performance to? Maybe you could be more explicit in showing the timings?  The pandas answer was also 40x but the numba answer was 4,000x (in each case, relative to the OP's method). I just left the pandas answer up as a point of comparison btw (b/c it is pure pandas), not that I think it is the best approach overall.

Comment: 40 times faster than the code in the question on the data from the question, on the very differently structured data in the numba answer its less due to less data per block, in that case a full cumprod followed with a division as in your pandas answer would likely be better.

Comment: Well, I played around with this some more and numpy vs numba results vary with the data structure a lot more than I would have thought...  I guess there is not all that much interest in the topic but I may try to do a more methodical comparison at some point in the future to try and figure out what the key parameters are.  Also, it looks like there will be some performance improvements to groupby in version 0.17.0 (planned for sept 2015?) so that may speed up the default approach here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fast but not very pretty workaround, you could do something like the following.  Here's some sample data and your default approach.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({ 'x':np.repeat(range(200),4), 'y':np.random.randn(800) })
df = df.sort('x')
df['cp_group'] = df.groupby('x').cumprod()
```

And here's the workaround.  It's looks rather long (it is) but each individual step is simple and fast.  (The timings are at the bottom.)  The key is simply to avoid using `groupby` at all in this case by replacing with `shift` and such -- but because of that you also need to make sure your data is sorted by the groupby column.

```
df['cp_nogroup'] = df.y.cumprod()
df['last'] = np.where( df.x == df.x.shift(-1), 0, df.y.cumprod() )
df['last'] = np.where( df['last'] == 0., np.nan, df['last'] )
df['last'] = df['last'].shift().ffill().fillna(1)
df['cp_fast'] = df['cp_nogroup'] / df['last']
df['dif'] = df.cp_group - df.cp_fast
```

Here's what it looks like.  'cp_group' is your default and 'cp_fast' is the above workaround.  If you look at the 'dif' column you'll see that several of these are off by very small amounts.  This is just a precision issue and not anything to worry about.

```
    x         y  cp_group  cp_nogroup      last   cp_fast           dif
0   0  1.364826  1.364826    1.364826  1.000000  1.364826  0.000000e+00
1   0  0.410126  0.559751    0.559751  1.000000  0.559751  0.000000e+00
2   0  0.894037  0.500438    0.500438  1.000000  0.500438  0.000000e+00
3   0  0.092296  0.046189    0.046189  1.000000  0.046189  0.000000e+00
4   1  1.262172  1.262172    0.058298  0.046189  1.262172  0.000000e+00
5   1  0.832328  1.050541    0.048523  0.046189  1.050541  2.220446e-16
6   1 -0.337245 -0.354289   -0.016364  0.046189 -0.354289 -5.551115e-17
7   1  0.758163 -0.268609   -0.012407  0.046189 -0.268609 -5.551115e-17
8   2 -1.025820 -1.025820    0.012727 -0.012407 -1.025820  0.000000e+00
9   2  1.175903 -1.206265    0.014966 -0.012407 -1.206265  0.000000e+00
```

**Timings**

Default method:

```
In [86]: %timeit df.groupby('x').cumprod()
10 loops, best of 3: 100 ms per loop
```

Standard `cumprod` but without the `groupby`.  This should be a good approximation of the maximum possible speed you could achieve.

```
In [87]: %timeit df.cumprod()
1000 loops, best of 3: 536 µs per loop
```

And here's the workaround:

```
In [88]: %%timeit
...: df['cp_nogroup'] = df.y.cumprod()
...: df['last'] = np.where( df.x == df.x.shift(-1), 0, df.y.cumprod() )
...: df['last'] = np.where( df['last'] == 0., np.nan, df['last'] )
...: df['last'] = df['last'].shift().ffill().fillna(1)
...: df['cp_fast'] = df['cp_nogroup'] / df['last']
...: df['dif'] = df.cp_group - df.cp_fast

100 loops, best of 3: 2.3 ms per loop
```

So the workaround is about 40x faster for this sample dataframe but the speedup will depend on the dataframe (in particular on the number of groups).